# Writing flexible code

Tags: version-control

How can I write flexible code?

I mean that; I wrote a application. Then I installed it to my customers pc and made some changes at code. Then I installed first application to my another customers pc and made some different changes at code. Now I want to make changes at my first application and install these to customers but I don't want to affect other customers special codes.

Answer (score 2):

Simple.  Use branching in your source control application.

For example SVN allows branching of code and thus allows users to maintain variations of their code.  This facility also allows merging meaning that if a feature implemented for client A would also be useful for client B then you can merge that feature into the code base for client B from that of client A.

Answer (score 0):

Branches is one way. Sort of like having two applications with some tools for merging. It will get sillas you add customers though.

The other way is modularising. So you could put the customer specific stuff into a dll, and then deploy the correct one.

Or you could do it via a meta-data. Config files, a database etc.

Or more likely a combination of the two.